# Podcast Player and Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, podcast, a2dp

I've been using Google Listen for podcast catching and playing. Seems to work just fine. I'd like to be able to play my podcasts over my Bluetooth headset. Alas, it seems that is only an option for A2DP bluetooth headsets(?) so I'm on a quest.

Can anyone offer suggestions? Seems like I have two options (but maybe there are others).

1. Find a podcast catcher/player that will play over a non-A2DP headset
2. Find a way to "fake" the Android into using a bluetooth headset even when not A2DP

Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

[edit]
I should mention that I'm running stock 2.1 and have no real desire to root/mod the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Super BT Mono](http://www.appbrain.com/app/super-bt-mono-froyo-pro/com.steven.supermonofroyopro).  It doesn't explicity say that it works for non-AD2P headsets but I believe that's the whole point of the app.  There'd be no need for this app with a headset that has AD2P.

**Edit:** Whoops, that's for Froyo only and you are on Eclair.

Basically you need to find an app that will stream audio over the HSP profile instead of AD2P but I couldn't find one for you.  You have 3 options as I see them:

1. Get Android 2.2 on your phone and Try [Super BT Mono Froyo Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/super-bt-mono-froyo-pro/com.steven.supermonofroyopro)
2. Root your phone, load CyanogenMod and try [Super BT Mono Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/super-bt-mono-pro/com.steven.superbtmonopro)
3. Buy a headset that supports AD2P *(they can be as cheap as $30)*

Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Looks intriguing. The description starts with "***Only work with cyanogenmod customed ROM or Nexus one." This leads me to believe it won't work for me(?)

Comment: You're looking at a different app than I linked to.  There's 4 different versions of Super BT Mono.  The one I linked to is "Super BT Mono Froyo Pro" and that one looks like its a more updated, better supported version.

Comment: This version just doesn't show up in "my version" of the market. Would the carrier block it?!? I've tried searching market and also tried via the QR code at appbrain.com. Not Found.

Comment: Sorry, that was a silly mistake on my part.  The title of the app is "Super BT Mono Froyo Pro" which I should probably have guessed is only compatible with Froyo and you are on Eclair.  That's why the market is blocking it.

Comment: Oh bummer. Sad day.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit. I'm hoping for Froyo someday, but haven't heard anything about Sprint's plan to update the Intercept.

Comment: Got Froyo update today from Sprint! Hope to revisit this soon...